# Why is my model importing to Unity in the wrong pose?

Tags: import, unity

I'm working on a humanoid model which I have in an A pose in Blender. It was originally in a T pose, but I changed the rest pose to an A pose because it was easier to work with for some of the meshes I was adding to the armature.

Now, when I import the model in Unity the body is in a T pose but the rest of the meshes are still in the A pose, like so:

[image]

Is this something I can fix in Blender? Obviously, I want everything to be in the same, correct pose when I import it. I don't have any animations on my model. All I did was reposition the arm bones and apply that new pose as a rest pose in the CATs plugin.

I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so since posting this I was able to figure out the issue with help from a friend. In case anyone else ever has the same issue, what solved it for me was related to shapekeys.

My issue was apparently niche enough that I couldn't find a solution because it was caused by using the CATs plugin to set the rest pose. For whatever reason, it must have not set the basis shapekey correctly on my body mesh when I changed the rest pose from a T pose to an A pose.

What I did to get it working was selecting the body mesh after confirming it was posed in the rest pose I wanted, creating a new shapekey and putting it in the first slot. Then I went into edit mode, selected the body material, clicked on vertex at the top of the window, and then blend from shape. Before clicking anywhere else, I changed which shapekey was selected in the dropdown (didn't seem to matter what I selected) and unchecked "add". Then I just moved that new shapekey down one slot, deleted the old basis shapekey and renamed my new one to basis.

Now when I export it as an fbx and import it to Unity is holds the correct pose.

So if you ever change your rest pose with the CATs plugin and it doesn't import correctly into Unity, try replacing the basis shapekey like I did and re-exporting it from blender. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I should probably mention what tipped us off to it not being a rotation issue or something was that even when all the meshes were combined the arms specifically were not aligned with the rest of the meshes, which were aligning correctly with the bones.

Since the basis shapekey was in wrong pose the body mesh was not aligning.

Answer (score 0):

Using Rigify addon after generating the rig, I made the bones visible from the hierarchy again with the current pose.

Then went into the pose mode, selected all bones, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and selected *Apply Selected as Rest Pose*.

If Rest pose is changing only in Unity then you should check the export values.